# Open a search in a iframe

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, search, browser

Before I say anything, yes, I know iframes are out of date. So I am trying to make a browser in html, a browser in a browser. I have a search bar which opens what you type in a new window, it searchs what you type on google, I want to make it so what you type opens the google search in the iframe, do you know how I could do this.

Html for search bar:

```
<form role="search" id="form">
                        <input type="search" id="query" name="q"
                       placeholder="Search..."
                       aria-label="Search through site content">
                        <button>
              <svg viewBox="0 0 1024 1024"><path class="path1" d="M848.471 928l-263.059-263.059c-48.941 36.706-110.118 55.059-177.412 55.059-171.294 0-312-140.706-312-312s140.706-312 312-312c171.294 0 312 140.706 312 312 0 67.294-24.471 128.471-55.059 177.412l263.059 263.059-79.529 79.529zM189.623 408.078c0 121.364 97.091 218.455 218.455 218.455s218.455-97.091 218.455-218.455c0-121.364-103.159-218.455-218.455-218.455-121.364 0-218.455 97.091-218.455 218.455z"></path></svg>

  <br>
  <iframe class="window" width="1000" height="600"></iframe>
```

JS for search bar:

```
const f = document.getElementById('form');
const q = document.getElementById('query');
const google = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=+';

function submitted(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const url = google + '+' + q.value;
  const win = window.open(url, '_blank');
  win.focus();
}

f.addEventListener('submit', submitted);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to open google in an iframe using this link: https://google.com/webhp?igu=1. If you wanted to implement this into your code it would be as follows

```html
<form role="search" id="form">
  <input type="search" id="query" name="q"
  placeholder="Search..."
  aria-label="Search through site content">
  <button>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 1024 1024"><path class="path1" d="M848.471 928l-263.059-263.059c-48.941 36.706-110.118 55.059-177.412 55.059-171.294 0-312-140.706-312-312s140.706-312 312-312c171.294 0 312 140.706 312 312 0 67.294-24.471 128.471-55.059 177.412l263.059 263.059-79.529 79.529zM189.623 408.078c0 121.364 97.091 218.455 218.455 218.455s218.455-97.091 218.455-218.455c0-121.364-103.159-218.455-218.455-218.455-121.364 0-218.455 97.091-218.455 218.455z"></path></svg>
  <br>
  <iframe class="window" width="1000" height="600"></iframe>
```

and the javascript would be

```js
const f = document.getElementById('form');
const q = document.getElementById('query');
const google = 'https://www.google.com/search?igu=1&q=';

function submitted(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const url = google + q.value;
  const win = window.open(url, '_blank');
  win.focus();
}

f.addEventListener('submit', submitted);
```